# RSS reader issue in air project

Tags: actionscript-3, air, rss-reader

I'm trying to build a simple adobe air application that reads an rss feed.

I succeeded in reading rss feeds, but I'm trying to read a specific one (provided by my school).
When I change the url from the rss reader that works, I get an HTTP Request Error:

> HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request"
>   faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL:
>   app:/url_req" errorID=2032]. URL: url_req"]

I tried many different ways to solve this but everytime I get no joy...

the HttpService is declared as follows:

```
<s:HTTPService id="lorenz" url="url_req" useProxy="false" />
```

where url_req is the variable with the url (which I can't give to protect my scholar data).

I did notice that when the url was entered in Interned Explorer it got an valid answer (firefox and chrome give an 500 error).

I am not an expert with rss, but I hope someone can help me with reading this feed.
I inculded the headers from the feed I got via IE, hope this will help

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cf="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005">
<channel xmlns:cfi="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005/internal" cfi:lastdownloaderror="None">
```

Comment: Maybe this could be relevant, since no one answerred so far, but the url is a secured one (https). I can get the data in the browsers now (maybe this was an error in the feeder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
Flex (or flash builder) can't seem to handle secure links very well...

> By default, a SWF file served over an unsecure protocol, such as HTTP, cannot access other documents served over the secure HTTPS protocol, even when those documents come from the same domain. ([adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_15.html))

So I had to come up with a workaround:
I created a php file that reads the secure content and passes it via a simple http protocol

the code:

```
$url="https:mySecuredUrl.com";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
echo $str;
```

now all I have to do is reading my feeds from the php file.